# escaping quotes in putty remote command

Tags: bash, quotes, putty, double-quotes, remotecommand

I have a less glorious task to solve, not much success so far.

I want to execute a remote script using "Remote command:" field in putty: `script param1 'param 2 with spaces'`

On linux simple escaping works well, i.e. `ssh user@remotehost script param1 \'param 2 with spaces\'`, but not on windows.

Please recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution - putty does the escaping for you.

The solution in this example is entering the remote command simply like: `script param1 'param 2 with spaces'`